# Validate against schema fragment

Tags: ruby, jsonschema

I'm new to json-schema so it might not be a relevant issue.
I'm using https://github.com/hoxworth/json-schema.
I have one big json file describing a lot of schemas (mostly small ones) with a lot $ref between schemas, and I need to be able to validate data against one of these "inner" schemas. I can't find a way to do this with json-schema.
Does json-schema support this use case, or am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: You don't tell us enough to work from. We can't see your code from here so we have no idea how you are processing the JSON or what you are doing with it. Maybe if you showed your code and told us the error you get it would help?

Comment: You could address a subschema if this implementation supported JSON Pointer, or if that subschema had an "id" to it and inline addressing were supported.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it does. It states that it uses the json schema v4. Also in the source code: line 265 lib/json-schema/validator.rb.

```
 def build_schemas(parent_schema)
  # Build ref schemas if they exist
  if parent_schema.schema["$ref"]
    load_ref_schema(parent_schema, parent_schema.schema["$ref"])
  end
```